# Retornar dados com formatação do banco de dados em um Textarea

Tags: php, mysql, formatação, textarea, tinymce

Boa noite, estou salvando os dados no banco de dados corretamente, ou seja no banco é gravado:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>teste negrito</strong></p> <p><strong>teste testes</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

porém quando tento inspecionar os dados no retorno dele para o textarea, esta primeira linha que está com style="text-align: center;", retorna sem esta formatação, ela retorna somente:

```
<p><strong>teste negrito</strong></p>
```

Para trazer os dados estou fazendo:

```
<textarea style="resize: none" name="campo" class="tiny form-control" rows="6"><?php echo ($retornoBanco);?></textarea>
```

Já olhei inúmeros comandos nativos do PHP para trazer essa formatação correta e não consigo, alguém pode me ajudar?
Obs: Estou usando o TinyMce para gerar os dados com esta formatação.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e carrega tudo normal.

Comment: sim, se vc tentar jogar dentro do textarea na "unha", ele vai mostrar corretamente, fiz este teste também, mas quando vem do banco as formatações style="" não são acatadas ou não vem com o  restante dos dados.

Comment: E se jogar dentro de uma div, funciona? O problema é o textarea? Ou já vem do banco sem o style?

Comment: penso que seja alguma limitação do textarea, mas queria ver se tem alguma opção que não conheço para continuar usando ele no modo de edição...

Comment: Hum... graças a sua sugestão de tentar utilizar o código em uma Div que consegui entender onde estava errando, tenho o hábito de enviar os dados usando addslashes, e recebe-los tbm, mas neste caso ao receber com addslashes ele estava reformatando o texto, só retirei ele para receber e o problema está resolvido!!!
Obrigado pela ajuda!!!